# What does ':' and '?' mean in the isClicked() symfony

Tags: php, symfony

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
// ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

$nextAction = $form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked()
    ? 'task_new'
    : 'task_success';

return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($nextAction));
}
```

Here is the link to the documentation

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

The class documentation says that it returns a bool.

What is the point of

```
? 'task_new' 
: 'task_sucess';
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is called "ternary" and it's awesome:

This is assigning the value `$nextAction` based on a condition. The first part (after the `=`) is the condition, like an `if` statement, the second part (after the `?`) is the value assigned if the condition is true, and the last part (after the `:`) is the value assigned if the condition is false.

```
               //the condition
$nextAction = $form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked()
    ? 'task_new' //true value
    : 'task_success'; //false value
```

It is a shorter way of writing this:

```
if ($form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked()) {
  $nextAction = 'task_new';
}
else {
  $nextAction = 'task_success';
}
```

So, here's some easy examples:

```
$foo = (true) ? 'True value!' : 'False value!';
echo $foo; //'True value!' of course!

$foo = (false) ? 'True value!' : 'False value!';
echo $foo; //'False value!' of course!
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the Ternary operator. The syntax is as follows:

```
value = (condition) ? run if true : run if false;
```

In this case, if `$form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked()` is true, then `task_new`. Else `task_success`.

If could be rewritten like so:

```
if($form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked()) {
    $value = "task_new";
} else {
    $value = "task_success";
}
```

Comment: You forgot `$` before `value`.

Comment: @n.1 Good call. Corrected it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is a shorter form for an if statement.
The : is the "else" part.
Example in Java:

```
boolean bool;
true ? bool = true : bool = false;
```

It's a senseless example, but shows the ternary operator very well.
if the condition, here true is "true", then fill into the variable bool true, else false.

alternative if-statement in Java to the code example above:

```
boolean bool;

    if(true)
        bool = true;
    else
        bool = false;
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! this answer would be better, if you posted an example of proper use and how it translates to an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Ternary Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) which is a short hand `if else` statement.  This is equivalent to

```
if($form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked()){
    $nextAction = 'task_new'
else{
    $nextAction = 'tassk_success'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the ternary opeator, a short-hand expression that works the same as an `if`

```
$value = someFunc() ? "whatever" : "the other"
```

is equivalent to

```
if (someFunc()) {
  $value = "whatever";
} else {
  $value = "the other";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to "if" and "else" statements.

This code :

```
$nextAction = $form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked()
    ? 'task_new'
    : 'task_success';
```

is equivalent to this code :

```
if ( $form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked() )
{
    $nextAction = 'task_new';
}
else
{
    $nextAction = 'task_success';
}
```